# How to make linear/more readable Java code with background/asynctask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

At the moment I have something like;

```
public class SomeActivity {
 void onCreate() {
  doSomething();
  if (weNeedToDoSomeAsncTask()) {
   new SomeAsyncTask(afterSomeAsyncTask).execute();
  } else {
   new DifferentAsyncTask(afterAnotherAsyncTask).execute();
  }
 }

 PostExecute afterSomeAsyncTask = new PostExecute() {
  void Callback(String response) {
   doSomethingElse(response);
   new DifferentAsyncTask(afterAnotherAsyncTask).execute();
  }
 }
}
```

This doesn't look too bad on the face of it, but I have hugely simplified the code and you can imagine how complex it becomes when you have more than a few calls going on and some branching starts to happen.

To help with context, the actual use case is normally something like;

- use an sdk to get some device/user information
- use the returned information to authenticate with a web service
- send some logging info to the web service
- get some data from the web service
- get some other data from the web service
- use that data to generate the UI

I would prefer my code to look a bit more like;

```
public class SomeActivity {
 void onCreate() {
  doSomething();
  if (weNeedToDoSomeAsncTask()) {
   new SomeAsyncTask().execute();
   doSomethingElse(response);
  } 
  new DifferentAsyncTask().execute();
  afterAnotherAsyncTask();
 }
}
```

I have tried used `.get()` in the past and had issues but never got to the bottom of why (potentially I was trying to call one `AsyncTask` inside another, which I've read is a no go- but it was a long time ago so can't be sure). Whilst I realise `.get` somewhat defeats the object of `AsyncTask`, I am only using it because Java forces me to (for network communication etc). My application is relying on the result to continue and can't do anything else till it returns anyway.

Should I try the `.get()` technique again? Or is it a really bad idea?

Should I just suck it up and realise the code is harder to read and I will need to jump to the callback methods to try and understand the code flow?

Or is there a different option?

I have also just learnt of Needle which looks like quite a nice library https://zsoltsafrany.github.io/needle/ and I think I could do more like;

```
NetworkService networkService = new NetworkService();
Needle.onBackgroundThread().serially().execute(networkService);
String result = doSomethingWithResponse(networkService.response);
AnotherNetworkService anotherNetworkService = new AnotherNetworkService(result);
Needle.onBackgroundThread().serially().execute(anotherNetworkService);
```

But perhaps this is exactly the same as the `AsyncTask.get()` approach?

Answer (score 1):

The TL;DR of any answer really will be: Kotlin coroutines.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) which you can obtain like:

```java
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(8);
```

There are numerous methods for scheduling futures.

Your first example might look like:

```
public class SomeActivity {
 void onCreate() {
  doSomething();
  if (weNeedToDoSomeAsncTask()) {
   executor.submit(() -> /* async task */);
   doSomethingElse(response);
  } 
  executor.submit(() -> /* different async task */)
  afterAnotherAsyncTask();
 }
}
```

(Although you'll need to look at the specific methods for alternatives to block/join.)